# Error While Running ANGULAR PROJECT , Tried using different versions of node using nvm but did not w

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Angular version screenshot
[image]

```
$ ng serve
\ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...node:internal/crypto/hash:69
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at BulkUpdateDecorator.hashFactory (Z:\WebDev\Internship\DocMgt\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:145:18)
    at BulkUpdateDecorator.update (Z:\WebDev\Internship\DocMgt\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:46:50) 
    at RawSource.updateHash (Z:\WebDev\Internship\DocMgt\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\webpack-sources\lib\RawSource.js:77:8)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (Z:\WebDev\Internship\DocMgt\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:880:17)  
    at handleParseResult (Z:\WebDev\Internship\DocMgt\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:946:10)
    at Z:\WebDev\Internship\DocMgt\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:1040:4
    at processResult (Z:\WebDev\Internship\DocMgt\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:755:11)
    at Z:\WebDev\Internship\DocMgt\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:819:5
    at Z:\WebDev\Internship\DocMgt\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:407:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (Z:\WebDev\Internship\DocMgt\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:10)   
    at iterateNormalLoaders (Z:\WebDev\Internship\DocMgt\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:240:10)   
    at Z:\WebDev\Internship\DocMgt\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:255:3
    at context.callback (Z:\WebDev\Internship\DocMgt\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:124:13)       
    at Object.loader (Z:\WebDev\Internship\DocMgt\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js:195:3) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Node.js v20.6.1
This error seems to be related to a missing or incorrectly referenced module, but I'm struggling to pinpoint the exact cause. I've double-checked my import statements, and they appear to be correct. The 'module-name' in question is part of my project's dependencies, and I've confirmed that it's installed.

I've already tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:

Clearing the Angular CLI and npm cache.
Reinstalling my project's dependencies using npm install.
Ensuring that the module's name is spelled correctly and matches the import statement.
Verifying that the module is listed in my project's package.json file.
My project was working fine before, and I haven't made any significant changes to the code recently. It's possible that there's an issue with my project configuration or some other subtle error that I'm overlooking.

I'm using Angular version X.X.X and Angular CLI version X.X.X. If anyone has encountered a similar error or has any insights on how to resolve it, I'd greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I've edited your question to remove the screenshot of the error since you've included the actual error text. No need for a picture of the same text. I also added code clocks around the error to make it readable, and removed the `angulsrjs` tag since this question is about Angular version 2 or higher and has nothing to do with the older and unsupported AnguarJS library.  Regarding your question, do you see the yellow text in your `ng v` output that says "The current version of Node (20.6.1) is not supported by Angular"?  I think that is your problem.  Either downgrade Node or upgrade Angular.

Comment: I tried downgrading Node did not work , i upgraded angular version but the project angular version is 12. something so it shows that

Answer (score 2):

Your error snapshot already says that the Node version is unsupported, and it's true.

If it's mandatory for you to use Angular version 12.x, then you should be using Node 14.x, and nothing higher.

For the most recent Angular version 16.x, you should be fine running with Node 16.x/18.x

Here is the compatibility chart:

- Actively supported Angular versions: https://angular.io/guide/versions#actively-supported-versions
- Unsupported Angular versions (your case) - https://angular.io/guide/versions#unsupported-angular-versions